# Should be printing ints. Prints address

Tags: c, pointers

I am following a tutorial series on youtube of C. In this particular video ([part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yzha37XR2Rg), [part 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aOlYcam6aNM)), he makes a report card program. As far as I can see, my code is exactly like his, but when I print out the integers of the grades, it prints the address of the ints. But it does print out the strings just fine. Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    int science, history, math, english;

} reportCard;

void printReportCard(reportCard *rc);

int main() {
    reportCard r1;
    r1.name = "Daniel Pendergast";
    r1.science = "80";
    r1.history = "90";
    r1.math = "100";
    r1.english = "80";

    printReportCard(&r1);
    return 0;
}

void printReportCard(reportCard *rc) {
    int average = (rc->science + rc->history + rc->math + rc->english) / 4;
    printf("Student's name: %s\nScience grade: %i\nHistory grade: %i\nMath grade: %i\nEnglish grade: %i\nOVERALL GRADE: %i",
    rc->name, rc->science, rc->history, rc->math, rc->english, average);
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? It should be screaming at you really hard. There is no way this could compile without errors/warnings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are assignment of char pointers to ints (if it's not clear, it's invalid):

```
r1.science = "80";
r1.history = "90";
r1.math = "100";
r1.english = "80";
```

Should be:

```
r1.science = 80;
r1.history = 90;
r1.math = 100;
r1.english = 80;
```

Did you check the compiler warnings?

Comment: Oh duh! Thanks a lot. The stupid CodeBlocks doesn't give me any warnings, and compiles just fine. Do you know if it is possible to turn on warnings?

Comment: Since this is only a single source file, you could also compile manually with `-Wall` to uncover any issues.

Answer (score 0):

`r1.science = "80";` - This will keep `80` as string in text segment(read only data) and then it will assign that virtual address of that string `80` to `r1.science`.

Assign values as integers like below

```
r1.science = 80; 
r1.history = 90; 
r1.math = 100; 
r1.english = 80;
```